# json_encode & mysql_escape_string - which way around?

Tags: php

Should I perform A json_encode before or after doing a mysql_escape_string?

```
json_encode($test);
```

Which way around is best?

Or does it not matter?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I don't want to use PDO thanks.

Comment: There is no good answer to this question. If you're using a deprectated extension, then no answer can really be helpful. Use a prepared statement...

Comment: Im not exactly going to upgrade an old project to use PDO am I for one simple update?

Comment: @panthro Depends how much you care about the security of your app

Comment: @panthro: No, you should've upgraded a couple of years ago... bet then: better late than never. Best not to wait until the extension is removed entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting data into the db, use

```
mysql_escape_string(json_encode($test));
```

**IF** and only **IF** you want to use the (deprecated) `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: There's no _if_ when it comes to `mysql_*` functions. There's only _don't_. It's deprecated, and will be removed some time in the future.

Comment: I am totally with you, Elias. However I understand panthro when it's about an old legacy code that he does not want to migrate the whole stuff only for that.

Comment: Sure, it's a tedious task to switch over to a newer, safer, more powerful and all-round better extension, but it's worth it. Besides: the deprecation of the extension was first discussed 3 years ago, and officially anounced in 2012. There's no excuse for spending time maintaining something that you _know_ issues notices on _stable_ versions of PHP

Comment: Friendly reminder, downvotes are supposed to be for things that don't resolve the problem. The asker has explicitly stated he wants to use mysql_* and doesn't want to switch.

Comment: @scragar That's not exclusively what downvotes are supposed to be for - the tooltip on the down arrow is "this answer is not useful". That covers a lot more than "doesn't resolve the problem", such as "Technically solves the problem, but with out-of-date and dangerous code"

Comment: Plus: I indicated that the responsibilty is with panthro by saying "if and only if...".

Comment: @Clive define:useful = "able to be used for a practical purpose", that sounds like the perfect definition for this answer. If you want to submit an answer suggesting he write his entire application you're more than welcome to do so, although that would clearly not be useful since the scope of the change would make it impractical for all but the smallest or best planned applications.

Comment: @scragar I'm not getting into a debate about semantics here - 'useful' means different things to different people in different contexts, as I'm sure you're aware. I find it sad that you think telling the OP to correct his insecure code is "clearly not...useful", preferring instead to encourage its use. I'd rather educate as to the dangers, but each to their own.

Comment: I think it's important he know the dangers, but he's been told, denying him access to information on how to do it the way he wants isn't going to make him change his mind, it's going to make him ask elsewhere. If he's told you "Im not exactly going to upgrade an old project to use PDO" then stop treating it like he doesn't know it's insecure, he's aware of the risk, he's assessed it as not worth the work required to resolve it. You're not educating him by downvoting people who want to help.

Comment: @scragar You've missed a fundamental point here. You are correct, I'm not trying to educate the OP; he doesn't want the information. But **this is not the OP's website**, and downvotes are not just for him. They're to warn other people in the future, who may not be able to see these comments, which could have been deleted, that something is potentially wrong with the answer. That's exactly what voting on Stack Exchange sites is for, whether you choose to subscribe to the fact or not